# Writing a program where the words inputted by the user gets checked for the same suffixes and then prints out how many of words with same suffixes

Tags: python, python-3.x

I already have the program where I ask the user how many words they want to input, after they engter how many times, the program then loops asking the user to input the words until the number of loops is completed. Here is the program:

```
def doSomething():
    x = int(input ("Enter how many words?\n"))
    for count in range (x):
       word1 = input (f"Enter word{count+1}:\n")
```

Now my problem is I want to check the suffixes of each of those words and then print out the number of words with the same suffixes. example (smash,trash,house,mouse) the number of words with the same suffixes is 2 here, like that.

Your Help Will Be Really Appreciated!
Thank you!!

Comment: One, what you have should fail to run (indentation is off). Two, take a look at the [str.endsswith()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) function and related string function in that same chapter.

Comment: oohh my bad but Thank you for the info!!